# Connection to jupyter server through VS code failed with Invalid response: 404 not found

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

The server is running normally and can be accessed through the browser but I prefer dealing with notebooks in VS code.

It used to work before i might have tweaked with something I don't remember but then I've reinstalled everything from the jupyter notebook packages to VS code extensions but I still get the error.

This is the response I get in the terminal where the server is running whenever i try to connect to the server.

```
[I 2023-09-01 09:01:47.560 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree/hub/api (@127.0.0.1) 1.00ms
[I 2023-09-01 09:01:47.565 JupyterNotebookApp] 302 GET /tree/tree? (@127.0.0.1) 0.00ms
[W 2023-09-01 09:01:47.585 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /tree/api/kernelspecs?1693548107568 (ee7498b315084c7bbf2975fb1678a013@127.0.0.1) 5.00ms referer=None
[W 2023-09-01 09:01:47.592 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /tree/api/sessions?1693548107577 (101794825c884428b6cd9040c7d25795@127.0.0.1) 6.00ms referer=None
[W 2023-09-01 09:01:47.601 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /tree/api/kernels?1693548107570 (24bb8ac606af4b349c4212bede39e1c0@127.0.0.1) 13.99ms referer=None 
[W 2023-09-01 09:01:47.606 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /tree/api/kernels?1693548107573 (f917befd05a34ed58fa785596a0b28c9@127.0.0.1) 17.99ms referer=None
[W 2023-09-01 09:01:47.618 JupyterNotebookApp] 404 GET /tree/api/kernelspecs?1693548107589 (c3c7abd352544efa9000194c706932d4@127.0.0.1) 7.99ms referer=None
```

Reinstalled the jupyter notebook packages and reset all the VS code extensions.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Are you connecting to the jupyter server with url like this?:

`http://example.com:8099/tree?token=08be37de0034706a01271ad3ce7e778612c1cbcf80d1dec5`

In my case, I found that if I removed the 'tree' from the url, like:

`http://example.com:8099/?token=08be37de0034706a01271ad3ce7e778612c1cbcf80d1dec5`

it would work.

Comment: This does not solve the issue. The jupyter server log still shows failed GET requests (404) to /hub/api and /login