# Connection to jupyter server through vscode fails with 404

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to connect to a local jupyter server. I can access the server just fine through the browser at http://127.0.0.1:8888/lab

However, when attempting to access the server through vscode (I prefer to work with notebooks this way), vscode makes GET calls to nonexisting locations and fails to connect.
This the jupyter server output when attempting to connect to the kernel with vscode:

```
[W 2023-10-13 11:39:13.850 ServerApp] 404 GET /hub/api (3d6066d144c148199057cfc52d470e24@172.17.0.1) 4.36ms referer=None
[W 2023-10-13 11:39:13.869 ServerApp] 404 GET /login? (cb81710be7fe4ba684e58543fe1d95d7@172.17.0.1) 1.78ms referer=None
```

I've tried reinstalling the jupyter notebook extension in vscode

Similar post here with no solution: [Connection to jupyter server through VS code failed with Invalid response: 404 not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77020878/connection-to-jupyter-server-through-vs-code-failed-with-invalid-response-404-n)